# Auto delete .ts and .m3u8 files once client receives all .ts files

Tags: express, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

So I created an express server that gets an mp3 file (which is stored locally right now, but will be taken from mongo db later) and uses ffmpeg to make .m3u8 and .ts files. The files are successfully sent to the client and there are no errors while playing it on the client. I used [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/) to play these files in Chrome. But the server still has those files stored locally. Is there any way the server can know when to delete these files that it stored locally? There are a lot of files generated by ffmpeg so I can't just let them stay there forever.

I used the ffmpeg part of code from [hls-server github repo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hls-server#producing-streams).

#### my server file

## index.js

```
// just used to run ffmpeg for conversion
var command = ffmpeg('inp.mp3')
  .on('start', function (commandLine) {
    console.log('command', commandLine);
  }).addOptions([
    '-c:a aac',
    '-b:a 64k',
    '-vn',
    '-hls_list_size 0',
    '-segment_time 10',
  ]).output('files\\output.m3u8');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
// express middleware to serve individual .ts and .m3u8 files when requested
app.use(express.static('./files/'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  command.on('end', function () {
    console.log('done');
    res.write(`
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/hls.js/latest/hls.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function onLevelLoaded (event, data) {
        var level_duration = data.details.totalduration;
        console.log(level_duration, data);
      }
      if(Hls.isSupported()) {
        var audio = new Audio();
        var hls = new Hls();
        // requesting files from here
        hls.loadSource('http://localhost:8000/output.m3u8');
        hls.attachMedia(audio);
        hls.on(Hls.Events.LEVEL_LOADED, onLevelLoaded);
        hls.on(Hls.Events.FRAG_BUFFERED, (e, d) => {
          console.log(e, d);
        });
      }
    </script>
    `);
    res.end();
  }).run();
});

app.listen(8000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `hls_delete_threshold`

```
"-hls_time 10",
"-hls_list_size 3",
"-hls_delete_threshold 3", 
"-hls_flags delete_segments"
```

> hls_delete_threshold `size`
>
> Set the number of unreferenced segments to keep on disk before
>   hls_flags delete_segments deletes them. Increase this to allow
>   continue clients to download segments which were recently referenced
>   in the playlist. Default value is 1, meaning segments older than
>   hls_list_size+1 will be deleted.

Comment: I know this is an old post but how would this be implemented on React. Because, I'm reading documentation and this is only referenced on FFMPEG. Does this mean that when the file is converted that flag should be provided or also when streaming. ps. I'm trying to make this work with React-Video-Player that supports hls.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do in my ffmpeg process:
`-hls_list_size 6 -hls_flags delete_segments`

That effectively rolls them. It automatically deletes the oldest one when creating a new one.

Now, I might be doing something wrong because I retain more than 6 files, but it certainly is deleting most of them.

Comment: Hey, this command does delete the segments but it does it while creating new ones... I want that once all segments are generated and sent to the client, then the  server deletes these files.. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I don't know if you can simply delete system files with javascript, but if you can, you'd use the "ended" event as a trigger `video.addEventListener("ended", myScript);`
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp

Comment: I'm running this file on a nodejs server so I can use fs module to delete the files.. and i did find an event that fires once the stream gets buffered completely. so i think i can do it with that

Comment: is  it because `-hls_flags delete_segments` is implemented only for live-streaming use case ? e.g. the live-stream video should be limited to access all segments so  `ffmpeg` deleted old segment beyond the threshold meanwhile create new segment ?

Comment: Yes, my example is actually used for live streaming and does not take the client (can be multiple) into account. So, it's definitely not a full solution to the OP.